# Parse json from JavaScript and create new one

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
[
 {“id”:”idtest1",”name”:”aaa"},
{“id”:”idlest2”,”name”:”bbb"},
{“id”:”idlest3","name”:"ccc"},
{“id”:”idtest4","name”:"ddd”}, 
… ]
```

I want to get only the name from these arrays. And I want to create a new array using name. The value of name becomes a key and adds a static string to the value.
The static value is increased by one. What should I do?

```
{
  “aaa" : [
    "static01value",  "static01value",  "static01value"
  ],
  “bbb" : [
    "static02value",  "static02value",  "static02value"
  ],
  …..
}
```

Comment: What is that static value in resulting json/map. How to calculate out static value ?

Comment: @Tejas static value is just a static string that I randomly specify. I want to add one by one after the static string

Comment: I can help till creating result json but I am not getting how to provide static value, so can you perform remaining things ? If you give any real example it will be helpful.

Comment: please use the correct quote or double quote.. your current code makes things confusing

Comment: @Tejas Oh, I made a mistake {
  “aaa" : [
   "static01value",  "static01value",  "static01value"
  ],
  “bbb" : [
    "static02value",  "static02value",  "static02value"
  ],
  …..
}

Comment: just updated my answer, again, it is a loosely answer because the question is not detailing all the requirement

Answer (score 2):

```js
let list = [
 {"id":"idtest1","name":"aaa"},
{"id":"idlest2","name":"bbb"},
{"id":"idlest3","name":"ccc"},
{"id":"idtest4","name":"ddd"}, 
]

let result = list.reduce((acc, {name}, i) => {
acc[name] = Array.from({ length: 3 }, () => `static0${i}value`);
return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

> You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method and use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method which
>   take a length for the array and a callback function which you can use
>   to modify that array

Comment: Nice use of `Array.from`!

Answer (score 0):

This is the snippet of what the code should look like, given that the static value is a bit vague:

```js
var array = [
  { id: "idtest1", name: "aaa" },
  { id: "idlest2", name: "bbb" },
  { id: "idlest3", name: "ccc" },
  { id: "idtest4", name: "ddd" }
];

var arrName = array.map(a => a.name),
    newArray = [];

arrName.forEach((a, idx) => {
  var newObject = {}
  newObject[a] = [];
  
  //not quite sure what your static value is, in your example you have 3 static value
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    newObject[a].push('static value' + idx);
  }
  
  newArray.push(newObject);
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below.

```js
var array = [
  { id: "idtest1", name: "aaa" },
  { id: "idlest2", name: "bbb" },
  { id: "idlest3", name: "ccc" },
  { id: "idtest4", name: "ddd" }
];

const result = {};

array.forEach((item, staticIndex) => {
  const staticArray = []
  // add static value to array
  staticArray.push('staticValue');
  result[item.name] = staticArray
})

console.log('Result array is ', result);
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 0):

Just try to parse your Json using es6 methods.

```js
const array = [
  { id: "idtest1", name: "aaa" },
  { id: "idlest2", name: "bbb" },
  { id: "idlest3", name: "ccc" },
  { id: "idtest4", name: "ddd" }
];

const your_static_content = 'your_static_content'

const output = array.reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj[item.name] = obj[item.name] || [];
  obj[item.name].push(your_static_content);
  return obj;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  { "id": "idtest1", "name": "aaa" },
  { "id": "idtest2", "name": "bbb" },
  { "id": "idtest3", "name": "ccc" },
  { "id": "idtest4", "name": "ddd" }
]

const getStaticValue = index => `static0${1 + index}value`

const result = data.reduce((result, {name}, index) => ({
    ...result,
    [name]: Array.from({length:3}, getStaticValue)
}), {})

console.log(result)
```